# Elastic Beanstalk Node codepipelne 'npm' failed to install dependencies that you defined in 'package.json'

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, npm, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Hi everyone I checked the logs full logs and last 100 lines and I can't seem to figure out why AWS is not installing whats in my package.json I get the error 'npm' failed to install dependencies that you defined in 'package.json'.

In my gitignore I have node_modules like this node_modules/ It would be silly to git push node_modules to the source code as that would destroy your github free account. I have no idea how to fix this. When I upload the zip to the environment it worked, but as soon as I added a code pipeline I get this error --> **'npm' failed to install dependencies that you defined in 'package.json'.**